# ASP.NET interactive chart control suggestion?

Tags: asp.net, charts, web-controls

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application and one of the requirements of the application is to have some data displayed using charts. I'm looking for an interactive ASP.NET Web Forms control that allows me to draw charts and also attach events so that I can make the chart "interactive". For example, when a user clicks on a "slice" in a "pie chart" control I need to know where the click is coming from so that I can update the rest of the page and display info regarding what that "slice" represents.

The controls I've seen so far seem to be good at generating charts but once the chart is generated there's not much that can be done.

I would appreciate any recommendation regarding a suitable charting control.

MadSeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is sources from a MS SQL Server database, then you could do your charts using Reporting Services. These use Dundas chart controls, and are quite interactive, allowing drill down functionality in your data.
From what I remember, Reporting Services is a free add on once you have a SQL Server licence.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/reporting-services.aspx

Comment: the data is from a MSSQL server database indeed but I am using an ORM ( Telerik Open Access ) to access the data .... :-(